# Unafe header waring when reading static map via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, http-headers

When I get static map image via AJAX to check for the error, I get:

**Refused to get unsafe header "x-staticmap-api-warning"**

(in chrome)

I don't know much about headers, but it seems they had to be allowed on the server. It is right? Or **is there anything I can do?**

For completion my code:

```
getImageUrl(mapAddress) {
    return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + encodeURIComponent(mapAddress) + "&markers=color:red%7C" + encodeURIComponent(mapAddress) + "&zoom=17&size=" + this.state.boxWidth + "x" + this.state.boxHeight + "&maptype=roadmap&key=" + GOOGLE_KEY;
}

getImage(mapAddress) {
    let url = this.getImageUrl(mapAddress);
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);

    // Ask for the result as an ArrayBuffer.
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    xhr.onload = (e) => {
        let warning;

        try {
            warning = xhr.getResponseHeader('x-staticmap-api-warning');
        } catch (e) {}

        if (warning && warning.indexOf('Error geocoding') === 0) {
            this.setState({
                imageFound: false,
                loading: false
            });
        }
        else {
            let imageBlob = new Blob([new window.Uint8Array(xhr.response)]);
            let imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);

            this.setState({
                imageFound: true,
                imageSrc: imageUrl,
                loading: false
            });
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to show a static map image on your page? If so, why not just put the url in an iframe.

Comment: I wanna show the map, when the address is found. And I don't want to make special request before to geo-API.

Comment: And as o iframe: Static image is more fast and as we will want to transition to server side rendering, iframe will not be suitable at all.

Comment: Ok the still doesn't explain why you are doing an ajax request, just add your url to the src of an img tag: `<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + encodeURIComponent(mapAddress) + "&markers=color:red%7C" + encodeURIComponent(mapAddress) + "&zoom=17&size=" + this.state.boxWidth + "x" + this.state.boxHeight + "&maptype=roadmap&key=" + GOOGLE_KEY;/>`

Comment: I do want ot show them "Address not found" in my style instead of empty google map with yellow warning. And static map return that error in the x-staticmap-api-warning header....

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue is, there's nothing wrong with your code. The issue is that the address you are using in `(mapaddress)` for the URL is incomplete or missing details.

In the documentation for [Static Maps API - Error Messages](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/error-messages#warnings) it says:

> For some error conditions, the API returns a map but some information may be missing from the map. When this happens, two conditions occur to inform you of the warning.
>
> One, the map displays, but with a yellow error bar superimposed over
> top of the map with the text "Map error: g.co/staticmaperror".
>
> Two,
> the API returns a warning in the form of an HTTP header named
> X-Staticmap-API-Warning.

I have also tried your URL replacing it with an address that works and it works fine.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=plaza+catalunya+barcelona&markers=color:red%7Cplaza+catalunya+barcelona&zoom=17&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&key=YOUR_KEY

Answer (score 0):

Did OP figure it out?

None of the answers works, because I and i assume OP as well, needs to simply not show the image if it can't find the address.

So we need to validate the address:

a) Either by geocoding address first, to check it's valid
b) or Listen for response header from static maps.

Seems like the latter is not an option... Just appears as a weird way google handles errors on their static maps service.

Comment: I made it work by workaround. I created server API function for this. So browser ask my server API, it load the response from google maps and checks this header to my heart content. And return the result to the browser or error message. It is not pretty but ... it works.